# problems with Haskell's Number Types

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I have the following haskell code:

```
fac n = product [1..n]

taylor3s w0 f f' f'' t h = w1 : taylor3s w1 f f' f'' (t+h) h
  where hp i = h^i / fac i
        w1 = w0 + (hp 1) * f t w0 + (hp 2) * f' t w0 + (hp 3) * f'' t w0

taylor_results = take 4 $ taylor3s 1 f f' f'' 1 0.25
  where f   t x = t^4 - 4*x/t
        f'  t x = 4*t^3 - 4*(f t x)/t + 4*x/t^2
        f'' t x = 12*t^2 - 4*(f' t x)/t + 8*(f t x)/t^2 - 8*x/t^3
```

taylor_results is supposed to be a use case of taylor3s. However, there is something wrong with the number type inferencing. When I try to compile, this is the error I get:

```
practice.hs:93:26:
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:
      `Integral a'
        arising from a use of `taylor3s' at practice.hs:93:26-51
      `Fractional a' arising from a use of `f' at practice.hs:93:37
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      taylor_results :: [a] (bound at practice.hs:93:0)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

Can someone help me with understanding what the problem is?

Comment: I always provide explicit types for top-level functions.  It makes the code easier to read, and when something like this happens it helps to narrow down the problem and help the compiler give meaningful error messages.  Without that all you know is there is a type error in there somewhere.

Comment: yeah normally I would too, but I'm pretty clueless on numerical types. Who knew there could be so many different types of numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're mixing operations that are only available on integrals and operations that are only available on fractionals (specifically you use `^` of which the second operand must be integral - use `**` if you intend for both operands to have the same Floating type), haskell infers that all arguments and the result of `taylor3s` have the type `Fractional a, Integral a => a`. This is not a type error, since theoretically such a type could exist, but it's most likely not what you want because in practice such a type does not exist.

The reason that you get a type error anyway is that the inferred type of `taylor_results` is consequently also `Fractional a, Integral a => a` which is polymorphic and thus violates the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

If you would explicitly declare `taylor_results` as `taylor_results :: Fractional a, Integral a => a` or disable the monomorphism restriction, the whole thing would compile, but be impossible to use (without defining a type that actually instantiates Integral and Fractional, which would be nonsense).

<strike>Note that if you fix this (for example by replacing `^` with `**`) the type of `taylor_results` will still be polymorphic (it will be inferred as `taylor_results :: (Floating a, Enum a) => [a]`, which is actually sensible), so you will still run into the monomorphism restriction. So you still need to either turn the restriction off, explicitly declare the type of `taylor_results` to be polymorphic or explicitly declare the type of `taylor_results` to be a specific type that instantiates Floating and Enum (e.g. Double). Note that unless you do the latter, `taylor_results` will be recalculated each time you use it (which is why the monomorphism restriction exists).</strike>

Note that if you fix this (for example by replacing `^` with `**`) the most general type of `taylor_results` will be `(Floating a, Enum a) => [a]`, however the type you get (unless you disable the monomorphism restriction) will be `[Double]`. If you don't want doubles, you either have to explicitly declare taylor_results to be of another type (which instantiates Floating and Enum) or to be polymorphic. Note that if you declare it to be polymorphic, `taylor_results` will be recalculated each time you use it (which is why the monomorphism restriction exists).

Comment: +1 For the ^/** answer. However Haskell will infer taylor_result as taylor_results :: [Double] due to the use of 0.25 ( i.e a Double type ) so there won't be any monomorphic restrictions

Comment: @zebrabox: The type of `0.25` is `0.25 :: (Fractional t) => t`, not Double. And the inferred type of taylor_results most definitely is `(Floating a, Enum a) => [a]` after replacing `^` with `**`. I actually checked this in ghci.

Comment: @zebrabox: Gah, I have to correct myself. *Without the monomorphism restriction* the inferred type will be `(Floating a, Enum a) => [a]`. However with the restriction enabled the type will just be specialized to `[Double]` without causing an error because of haskell's defaulting rules regarding Numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Haskell is inferring the return of `taylor3s` as being an `Integral` type, but then the fact that the subfunctions `f` etc are inferred as dealing with `Fractional` types violates that inference.

Perhaps by explicitly telling Haskell the `taylor3s` return type might help.